# extendedSummary Yiiboster not show the sum total of gridview

Tags: yii

I have gridview using TbExtendedGridView yii booster, in footer gridview i want show the sum of field using extendedSummary, i have follow the tutorial in yiibooster web but i can't show the extendedSummary to show the sum of column. Pls help me what's wrong in my code below ?. in the footer just show the box with blank text.

```
//this isi my gridview code
$no_loan= $_GET[no_loan];
$sql2="SELECT * from tbangsuran where nomor_pinjaman = '$no_loan' and status_bayar=1 order by no ASC";
$sqlProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql2);

 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    //'filter'=>$model,
        'id'=>'tbangsuran-grid',
        'type'=>'striped bordered',
     'template' => "{items}\n{extendedSummary}",
    'dataProvider' =>$sqlProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
          array(
                'name'=>'Angsuran Ke',
                 'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center; width:90px;'),
                 'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center'
                 ),
                'value'=> '$data[\'no\']',
            ),
             array(
                'name'=>'Tanggal Tagihan',
                 'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;width:90px;'),
                 'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center'),
                'value'=> 'date("d-m-Y",strtotime($data[\'tanggal_bayar\']))',
            ),
        //'nomor_pinjaman',
             array(
                 'name'=>'Tunggakan Pokok',
                 'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center; width:120px;'),
                 'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:right'),
                'value'=> 'number_format($data[\'pastdue_pokok\'],0,"",".")',
            ),
             array(
                 'name'=>'Tunggakan Bunga',
                 'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center; width:120px;'),
                 'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:right'),
                'value'=> 'number_format($data[\'pastdue_bunga\'],0,"",".")',
            ),
              array(
                'name'=>'Total Tunggakan',
                 'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;width:120px;'),
                 'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:right'),
                'value'=> 'number_format($data[\'pastdue_pokok\']+$data[\'pastdue_bunga\'],0,"",".")',
            ),
    ),
    'extendedSummary' => array(
        'title' => 'Total Tunggakan',
          'columns' => array(
            'pastdue_pokok' => array('label'=>'Total Tunggakan','class'=>'TbSumOperation')
        )
    ),
    'extendedSummaryOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'well pull-right',
        'style' => 'width:300px'
    ),

    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same column name in extendedSummary field.

In your case would be:

```
'extendedSummary' => array(
    'title' => 'Total Tunggakan',
      'columns' => array(
        'Total Tunggakan' => array('label'=>'Total Tunggakan','class'=>'TbSumOperation')
    )
),
```

I recommend you to use short column name to this tasks.

Hope this helps!